# Reading file using file.read logic in Interactor

Tags: interactor-backend

[interactor] workspace-test > run file.read /Users/mycomputer/Desktop/test.txt

:enoent

[interactor] workspace-test >

Above is what I get when I run file.read logic.
Q1. What does the error message :enoent mean?
Q2. How can I check whether Interactor has read the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:enoent stands for "error no entity" which means that the file does not exist.  You may want to double check that you got the file path correct.

You can also use the [file.exist](https://www.interactor.com/developers/docs#file.exist) function to handle non-existing files in your logic.  For example:

```
service read : map
  # 1: file_path
  on start : if (file.exist $1) (file.read $1) (event error)
  on error : list
    error = 'File does not exist: $1'
    log 'service.read.error' $error
    throw $error
  exit
exit
```